# Delete timer-queue timer

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

I can't delete my Timer Queue properly. I always get the following error: Unhandled exception at 0x77a915de in Timer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.

I have a simple timer callback function:

```
void CALLBACK TimerProc(void* lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    cout << "The timer is working!" << endl;
}
```

And here is my main function where I create and delete the timer:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hTimer;

    // Create timer
    CreateTimerQueueTimer(
                            &hTimer,                         // Timer handler
                            NULL,                            // Default timerqueue
                            (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TimerProc,  // Callback function
                            0,                                          
                            0,
                            (DWORD)2000,                     // Period value = 2 seconds
                            WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD );

    // Do other tasks
    // e.g. Sleep(10000);

    // Delete Timer
    if ( !DeleteTimerQueueEx(hTimer, NULL) )
    {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The debugger always stops at the DeleteTimerQueueEx line. Why does this failure occurs?

Comment: What is the value of hTimer? I suspect -1

Comment: You are adding to the default timer queue as you are not creating your own (CreateTimerQueue) and IIRC you cannot delete it, instead delete the timer itself (DeleteTimerQueueTimer) - or if you want to group multiple timers, create your own queue.

Comment: The value of hTimer is a positive integer. @Alex K.:(DeleteTimerQueueTimer) works properly.

Comment: @Alex K: You should make that an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not creating your own queue ([`CreateTimerQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682483.aspx)) rather you are adding to the default timer queue which is not deletable, instead delete the timer itself ([`DeleteTimerQueueTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682569.aspx)).

If you want to group multiple timers, create your own queue which you can then subsequently delete.